# Auto attach Jolokia on application restart

Tags: jmx, jolokia

I have been trying to attach Jolokia dynamically using the following command:

```
java -jar jolokia-jvm-1.3.4-agent.jar start <myapplication_regex>
```

This works successfully. But on application restart, Jolokia terminates.

Is there any workaround for handling the application restart case?

Comment: You can include the line  `java -jar jolokia-jvm-1.3.4-agent.jar......` at the end of your application start-up script , which can resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `-javaagent:/path/to/jolokia-jvm-<version>-agent.jar` to the application properties so that it gets attached on restart.